# g++ -shared argument seems to be causing a segmentation fault

Tags: python, c++, boost, compiler-errors, embedding

I am just getting started learning cpp, coming from a background in python and java.  A few days ago I decided to try and mess around with python embedding in cpp using boost.  I got the library installed, and I tried for a long time to get it working.  However, no matter what I did, I kept running into a segmentation fault.  At first I just assumed that I was doing something wrong with including the library, but eventually, I discovered that I still got the segfault even after removing all of the code related to boost from my program.  I even converted the program into a simple hello world and still got the segfault!  Here is what my program looks like now:

```
//#include <boost/python.hpp>
//#include <Python.h>
//using namespace boost::python;

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  //Py_Initialize();
  cout << "Test";
}
```

I compiled the code using these two commands:

```
gcc -c boost.cpp -o boost.o -fPIC
g++ boost.o -o boost -shared
```

and this is the output of running the compiled program:

```
Segmentation fault
```

Upon further messing around, I discovered that if I removed the **-shared** argument:

```
g++ boost.o -o boost
```

The program would run as expected.  This would be fine, except that in order to include the boost library the compiler needs this argument.  If I attempt to uncomment the `#include <boost/python.hpp>` line in my code and recompile without the **-shared** argument, I get this error:

```
boost.o: In function `boost::python::api::object::object()':
boost.cpp: (.text._ZN5boost6python3api6objectC2Ev[_ZN5boost6python3api6objectC5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `_Py_NoneStruct'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea what is going on.  I am doing this on ubuntu, and I installed boost by using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

I am still relatively new to cpp, so if I have done something completely stupid, feel free to let me know!  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: if you are still getting the error then perhaps you might be having memory leaks. try to restart your computer and re-run your last code to see if the error goes away

Comment: One obvious fault is that you're using `gcc` with C++ code. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `-shared` to link with the boost libraries. You need to add the python libraries too to resolve the undefined reference to `_Py_NoneStruct`.

Note that the order of the libraries is important:

```
 g++ boost.cpp -o boost -lboost_python38 -lpython3.8
```

Here I've added the `boost_mpi_python` libraries too in case you need them:

```
g++ boost.cpp -o boost -lboost_mpi_python38 -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization -lboost_python38 -lpython3.8
```

Replace `3.8` (and `38`) with the actual version you have on your system.